# Windows Phone XNA MediaPlayer rewind/fast forward functionality

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, media-player, xna-4.0

Is there a way to rewind/fast forward (or at least start playing at a certain position of a track) a media that is being played (using XNA.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer static instance) from a Media Library integrated application on Windows Phone Mango?

BTW: I have created a feature request on wpdev user voice community, so if you are in need of the similar functionality, go ahead and make a vote: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/2459380-allow-setting-a-playback-start-position-within-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XNA 4.0 there is no real way of doing this using `MediaPlayer` unless there are undocumented hacks to get it to. But definitely there are no documented ways of doing this with the `MediaPlayer` class.

Comment: Thank you. Please consider placing a vote to increase chanses of this feature appearing in the next releases.